# How to automatically login with VB Login form code?

Tags: visual-studio, authentication

Say username is `ADMIN` and password is `ADMIN`.
It should be auto **LOGIN** and it's not showing **FORM 3**. What would the code be for Visual Basic. Is mine correct?

> My form output:

[image: Login form]

> Here's my example code:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "" And TextBox2.Text <> "" Then
        MsgBox("Invalid username and password, Please try again!", +vbExclamation, +vbOK)


    ElseIf TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.Username And
    TextBox2.Text = My.Settings.Password Then
        MsgBox("Login Successfuly! Good day.", +vbInformation, +vbOK)
        Form3.Show()
        Me.Hide()

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields.", "Authentication Error" + TextBox1.Text + TextBox2.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your first if condition is wrong. You want = not <>

Answer (score 0):

Below code is simple login form button click event code.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       If TextBox1.Text = "rfb" And TextBox2.Text = "reflection" Then
           Form2.Show()
       Else
           MsgBox("Sorry, username or password not found", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid")
       End If
   End Sub
```

change code as your needs.

You can change the username and the password in the code where it says "rfb" for the username and "reflection" for the password. - See more at: http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/form/LoginT.htm#sthash.yb1ihiFB.dpuf

hope this will help

Comment: In this part I've done it correctly. But my problem is it wont allow me to login to another form :(

Comment: It will close automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I use next code for login:

```
    Dim user As String = UsernameTextBox.Text
    Dim pass As String = PasswordTextBox.Text
    Dim sts As Integer = 0
    If user = My.Settings.UeserName Then
        sts = sts + 1
    Else
        MsgBox("User name not found , Please,Try again.Or Contect Adminstrtor for help", vbOK, "login error")
    End If
    If pass = My.Settings.Password Then
        sts = sts + 10
    Else
        MsgBox("User name not found , Please,Try again.Or Contect Adminstrtor for help", vbOK, "login error")
    End If

    If sts = 11 Then
        hello.Enabled = Enabled
        Me.Close()
    End If
```